# Angularjs - what are the possible reasons for duplicate records being inserted by the following code?

Tags: sql, angularjs, api, duplicates, record

The following code is called on the click of a button

```
$scope.someFunction = function () {
     $scope.submitting = true;     // the button is disabled if submitting is true
     var query = { query: { id: $scope.employeeID } };

     // this api call inserts a record in a table
     httpFactory.patch("/someURL", query).then(function (data) {
          $scope.submitting = false;
                if (data.error) {
                    // display error message
                }
                else {
                    // display success message
                }
                $scope.submitting = false;
            }, function () {
                $scope.submitting = false;
            });
        };
```

can duplicate records be inserted from the call above if a user has poor connectivity or if the server is slow and the request is not completed and soon another same request is received?

If so.. could any one please suggest a suitable way to handle this?

Comment: Why is a `patch` call being translated to an insertion? It seems like you should be using `post` instead. Also note there's nothing stopping a (malicious) user from subverting the UI and invoking this function to repeatedly trigger the API call. As such, you should handle that possibility in your API call.

Comment: @miqh would it make sense to use ```patch``` if there is actually updates happening along with insertion? in the original post I only mentioned insert for simplicity...